# Code block markdown missing from question & answer summaries

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, code-block

The answer summaries shown in search results appear to strip out code block markdown from the text. For example, the second item in [this query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:622391+[java]) doesn't show the code block markdown content of this phrase:

> "As you remove characters, `Cleaner` becomes shorter, so you're likely to reach a point where `x` is too large."

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @bluet, I didn't think of looking on `meta.so` before posting - sorry! This is actually a problem on other stackexchange sites anyway - here's an example on codereview.se: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22commands+and+capturing+their+output+is+deprecated%22

Comment: This is technically code between backticks, not just any Markdown.

Comment: @Dan, I didn't say it was! I couldn't say how many forms of markdown are affected, but it's clearly a markdown issue. I've no doubt the extent of the problem will be clear once someone looks into it.

Comment: I broke this intentionally a while ago, not considering the consequences of my actions. I'll work on a fix this week. It's trickier than it appears, if that makes anyone feel better. ;)

Comment: @Simon since it's affecting network-wide, it's OK to post here without checking MSO first. Also, I tried to focus the problem on `code-block` first, since it's the only visible case (I prefer more focused bug report). If there is another markdown affected, feel free to incorporate to the question. In any cases, Haney should already know the cause :)

Comment: I've got a fix in place. We're waiting until the weekend to deploy it because it requires a full re-index which blocks devs. I'll be kicking off the fix Friday evening EST time so that it should be working again Saturday by noon EST. A re-index is currently 27.2 million records, so it takes a while. ;)

Comment: I'm deploying the fix now. ETA ~8 hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. I broke this *intentionally* a few weeks back, without properly considering the implications of my actions. It has now been fixed. Super sorry for the inconvenience! Please check now and you'll find that code once again appears in search results.

Comment: So, [tag:status-completed]? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard ahh yes, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, and enjoy the incoming bounty! (if bluet won't forget ;))

Comment: Thanks @Haney! If it's not giving away internal secrets, would you mind explaining why you broke it intentionally?

Comment: Sure @SimonMᶜKenzie - the tl;dr is that we *were* analyzing code and post body with the same search analyzer. I separated out code into its own field, analyzed in a way more appropriate for code, however this removed it from body. So now, code and body are still their own independent fields, but I display a new field, bodyWithCode in the results to give you a proper experience. bodyWithCode is not searched, just displayed. :)

Comment: Also, we have very few internal secrets: most of them are related to finances of the company. We are Default Public.

Comment: @Haney great, so where can I find copy of the code behind? :-D

Comment: @ShadowWizard what code behind? This thing runs of magic unicorn dust.

Answer (score 4):

This was fixed earlier by [Haney](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/262550/haney)

> I'm deploying the fix now. ETA ~8 hours.

It appears as though the re-indexing is completed (or getting close to it). The search query referenced now displays the second result correctly.

[image: The second result has some code]