# able to choose reward existing answer option even though there are no existing answers

Tags: bug, bounties, bounty-dialog

I started a bounty *just now* on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247802/markdown-missing-from-answer-summaries). The "Reward existing answer" reason was visible so I chose that option and the system let me use it even though there are no existing answers *(AnswerCount=0)*.